# Is it possible to set a gif image in base64 as responsive?

Tags: image, responsive-design, gif

I have the next code:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Goerman</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <center>
        <div id="image">
            <img alt="Embebed Image" src="data:image/gif; base64,R0lG--IMAGE IN BASE64--="/>        
        </div>
    </center>
    </body>
</head>
```

I need that the animate image auto-set to screen the device or size of the navigator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following class to your style sheet and the corresponding class to your img tag

```
<style>
  .responsiveImage {max-width: 100%; width: auto; height: auto;}
</style>


<img src="data:image/gif; base64,R0lG--IMAGE IN BASE64--=" class="responsiveImage" />
```